# Using IdentityServer4 for SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, identityserver4

Hi everyone I am new to Identity Server and .net core and I went through all the documentation however I still don't understand how to setup the ids4 for SSO between 2 applications without the user need to login into identity server. 
The scenario is as follow, user is logged in in app 1 (my application) and clicks a button to login to app 2 (external application which supports openId connect). I have to setup the identity server as the external app only supports SSO via openId.
How do I implement this without asking my user to login to identity server again as they are already logged in my app? Is it any way I can log them in to identity server when they login to my app and maintain the session or mark them as logged in all the time? Or any other solutions I can accomplish this scenario?
Both applications are web based.

Comment: well in case someone is in the same boat as me, basically I have to setup the 2 apps as clients so on the initial login in app1 I redirect to IDS and login there and then into my app1. Then when user clicks on a link to SSO to app 2, when app2 redirects to IDS the user is already logged in so they should not see the login screen but get the id token directly. As my app1 and IDS belong to same organization i use implicit flow and for 3rd party app2 authorization code.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @cvetyab, in your situation if the user logs into app2 first then navigates to app1, he is not logged into app1 right?  He must click login in app1 then silently visit the identity server and return to app1 logged in right?  Have you found a way to do true SSO between the identity server and app1?

Comment: You need to tie the both of the logging to the same user, then when the user logs in the first time it provides all the scopes in which they have access to or, you have your app silently check if they have access to app2